# How to substract values in order to have a positive result in an SQL select?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to a query that substracts a number `B` to number `A`. The only condition is that the result has to be a positive number so if `A > B` then the operation has to be `A - B` and if `B > A` then the operation should be `B - A`.

Is it possible to do this using only a `SELECT` clause or I should create a stored procedure?

If so, how can I do this properly using a `SELECT` clause like the following?

```
select A - B from foo;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach 1:**

You can use `ABS()` function

```
SELECT ABS(2-5);
```

**Approach 2:**

You can use `CASE` clause:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 5>2 THEN 5-2 ELSE 2-5 END;
```